# Unable to empty the rubbish bin

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, trash

When I attempt to empty the rubbish bin the preparing window opens but nothing happens.
In testing I tried to delete 1 file from the rubbish bin and received a time-out error. 
No files are removed from the rubbish bin after this.

I have added a screen shot that includes a display of system monitor that shows high CPU usage for trash and Nautilus; not sure whether it is related.

[image]

<sup>Click for a full-resolution image.</sup>

Also, on a separated note, Bleachbit was also freezing on me, which may or may not be related?

Comment: The trash is located at `~/.local/share/Trash` what happens if you go in there and manually delete?

Comment: Thank you @Mitch . Went to this folder and manually deleted the contents. I think the issue may have being with folder contained within the rubbish bin from picture above. It contained a load of files (192K) but then could not find them when it came to delete so I just clicked skip all button and everything was removed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not coincidentally I had this problem also twice after using Bleachbit. In both cases, it may have happened when I had to shutdown Bleachbit before it finished executing because it appeared to have frozen (several hours but my drive is not very big).

In my case, I had accidentally set it to clean the empty space and, having frozen / killed it during this process, it appears to have left a randomly named folder filled with many many files which, I believe (but don't know for sure), are created as part of the process of wiping the free space on the hard drive. (Nautilus could never actually display the files - it just showed the busy icon while trying to load them so I assume that they were the many files created as a result of the drive cleaning process.)

As Mitch said I finally worked out that I could only empty the trash of these files by deleting the hidden directory `~/.local/share/Trash/files`.

Credit to Mitch for answering this question (if he re-posts it as an answer) but I thought my experience would elucidate one possible cause of this problem i.e. if you had to kill Bleachbit, or it crashed, it may have left damaged files behind that could not be normally deleted.